# Text Field Fill Up Rest of Horizontal Space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu where the text input field `.search-form` will expand to take up the rest of the available horizontal space within `.container`. I also have a `.cart`, `.logo`, and `.menu` which has a width based on their content.

Currently, I am able to get everything to work, except that the `.search-btn` is on a different line then `.search-form` and I do not know how to fix this. It is important that `.search-btn` and `.search-form` are contained by the same div as I will create a drop-down that appears containing potential search results. This drop-down will have to be the same width of `.search-btn` and `.search-form`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnJPE/1/

html:

```
<div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="cart">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/27x27">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x27">
    </a>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">
            Item 01
        </a> </li>
        <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">
            Item 02
        </a> </li>
        <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">
            Item 03
        </a> </li>
        <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">
            Item 04
        </a> </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="search">
        <input class="search-form" type="text" value="varying width">
        <a href="search-btn"><img class="search-icon" src="http://www.placehold.it/20x20"></a>
        <div class="suggestions">
            Potential Results Goes Here
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    height:30px;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.logo{
    float:left;
}

.search{
    overflow: hidden;
    background:aqua;
}

    .search > .search-form {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .search > .search-btn {
        width: 27px;        
    }

    .suggestions {
        background: #98faf9;
        height: 50px;
    }

.menu {
    float: left;
}

    .menu > .item {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

.cart{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `.search`, remove `overflow: hidden` as it's not needed, and use `float: right`. For the `.search-form` remove the `width: 100%`, because this prevents the button to move to the right, or set it to the initial of `auto`

```
.search {
    background:aqua;
    float: right;
}

.search > .search-form {
}
```

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnJPE/30/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.search > .search-form {
    width: auto;
}
```

instead of

```
.search > .search-form {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.search` add `white-space: nowrap;`

http://jsfiddle.net/WTsqK/